# How to remove these application icons?

Tags: wine, icons, uninstall, .desktop, activities-overview

I once install LINE Messenger in my Ubuntu's using Wine. Then I remove it using the LINE Uninstall icon because the application like to hang my computer.

[image: The icons]

Any idea how I can remove these icons? I've check the `/usr/share/applications` but it's not there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should find the associated `.desktop` files in your `~/.local/share/applications/` directory.

Remove the associated `.desktop` file if you want to get rid of the application launcher from Activities overview or add a `NoDisplay=true` line inside the file to simply hide it.